# radio box input stores "on" as database value

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

radio box input doesn't store the value instead shows "on" in the database
here is my code.

```
            <label for="gender">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender">
            <label for="gender">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender">
            <label for="gender">Transgender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender">
            <span class="formerror"></span>
```

this is my schema

```
gender: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
```

this is the data in the database stored

```
{
  name: 'Ethan Hunt',
  age: 60,
  gender: 'on',
  blood_group: 'B+',
  date: 2023-07-05T00:00:00.000Z,
  phone_number: '7074788341',
  medical_history: 'cataract',
  password: '1234',
  _id: new ObjectId("64a1bced4796f50508c67030"),
  __v: 0
}
```

i was expecting the gender value to show up as "male" "female" or "transgender".

i also tried adding

```
gender: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["female", "male", "transgender"],
        required: true
      },
```

but it generates an error
"Detail validation failed: gender: `on` is not a valid enum value for path `gender`.
at ValidationError"

Comment: We need the code that gets the values and sends them to the database.

Comment: Just showing that is not enough, we need the JS context. But only reading that HTML code, the inputs are missing the attribute value.  E.g. `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>`

Answer (score 1):

give your html element a "value" attribute and set it's value to the gender value it denotes.

also read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute
for more insight on accessing the value via javaScript

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each option/radio button a value. And now you can ask for the value on the name (`gender`). The `e.target` in the submit event callback is the form element.

The `for` attribute on `<label>` only work for IDs. Skip the IDs and have the input as a child to label will work fine.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.gender.value);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required></label>
  <label>Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"></label>
  <label>Transgender <input type="radio" name="gender" value="transgender"></label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```